# How to increase the time to execute a request to server?

Tags: google-chrome, request, frontend, devops, response

I need to create jasper report on server in html and paste it in iframe on my front. But this request is not fast, it took around 2-4 min depending on filters. In Chrome limits set 2 minutes, after 2 min. connection to server closing (status: `(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`). How to solve it?

Devops said, they set proxy timeout to 6 min and it still dont work.